# Git Log Print Ref Metadata to File

Tags: git, git-log

When I run `git log` and view in the pager I get some nice ref metadata next to commits:

```
commit 212b18778130cdf36effe441890826b76b97a09f (HEAD -> master, tag: TAG_8.0.2, origin/author/bootstrap_gcm, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 4d7e0962f 7f687a431
Author: Joe, Smith <joe.smith@company.com>
Date:   Sun Oct 4 18:03:37 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'jsmith/8.0.0_changes' into 'master'

    See merge request project/project!1286

commit 4d7e0962fadc17ac3af23a85b64ecaf65d68bc42 (tag: TAG_8.0.1)
Merge: e7ccb690f cd10de563
Author: Joe, Smith <joe.smith@company.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 2 19:54:31 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'project2' into 'master'

    See merge request project/project!1285
```

The ref metadata I am talking about is:

```
(HEAD -> master, tag: TAG_8.0.2, origin/author/feature_br1, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
(tag: TAG_8.0.1)
```

-- Off to the right of the commit in parenthesis.

However, if I do `git --no-pager log > git.log`, all that ref info is missing:

```
commit 212b18778130cdf36effe441890826b76b97a09f
Merge: 4d7e0962f 7f687a431
Author: Joe, Smith <joe.smith@company.com>
Date:   Sun Oct 4 18:03:37 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'jsmith/8.0.0_changes' into 'master'

    See merge request project/project!1286

commit 4d7e0962fadc17ac3af23a85b64ecaf65d68bc42
Merge: e7ccb690f cd10de563
Author: Joe, Smith <joe.smith@company.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 2 19:54:31 2020 -0400

    Merge branch 'project2' into 'master'

    See merge request project/project!1285
```

Two questions.

1. Why? Shouldn't the same text sent to the pager also be redirected to a file?
2. Is there a way I can preserve the ref info in parenthesis when dumping to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the same text sent to the pager also be redirected to a file?

No: the default setting for `decorate` is `decorate=auto`, and *auto* means:

- on (set to `short`) when going to the screen (perhaps through a pager), but
- off (set to `no`) when going to a file.

That's precisely why:

> ```
> git --no-pager log --decorate > git.log
> ```

works: `--decorate` is short for setting the `decorate` setting to `short`, for the execution of this one command.

Note that using `git config`, you can configure your own personal default setting for the `decorate` option.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config); search for `log.decorate`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what the answer to my first question is (why is the ref information that is present in the pager is not dumped to file). However, I found a workaround - including the `--decorate` flag:

```
git --no-pager log --decorate > git.log
```

It's not *exactly* the same, but it's enough for my purposes.