# Why do git branch and tag annotations in git log disappear if you pipe it to more?

Tags: git, cmdline-args

git version 2.20.1

```
(base) piadmin@pi-spec1:~/pi$ git log
commit 2851703321fd8d026c51621dd9553f2cec92a6c0 (HEAD -> PI_InFactory, tag: PI_shipped_20220310, origin/PI_InFactory)
Author: David <dac@me.ca>
Date:   Thu Mar 10 10:08:34 2022 -0500

    Fix classes to match PI, on commented line, for agile customer support


(base) piadmin@pi-spec1:~/pi$ git log | more -20
commit 2851703321fd8d026c51621dd9553f2cec92a6c0
Author: David <dac@me.ca>
Date:   Thu Mar 10 10:08:34 2022 -0500

    Fix classes to match PI, on commented line, for agile customer support
```

Notice what's missing on the "commit" line when I used "more"?

Clarification edit:  When I ask "why", it's because in my decades of linux experience, I've never seen output change (besides loss of colour) when piping something to `more`.  It seems to me like a foundational concept of command line *nix, and the pipe architecture, that this cannot happen, so I guess I mean both "how?" and "why?".

After the answer from @LeonardoDagnino, I see that I should expect this behaviour if I typed `git log --decorate=auto`, but I am not adding this argument, and the help says the default option should be 'short' anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "why"? Because it was programmed that way. https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/log.c#L78

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218975/7976758

Comment: Note: this has a much better / more searchable *title* than the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page git-log(1) ([since version 3.33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0538e5c8baf9985a71d18a1495985441041efba)) explains that the default behaviour for `--decorate` is `auto`, and what it does changes whether you are running in a terminal or not:

```
   --no-decorate, --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
       <...>
       If auto is specified, then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref
       names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown.
       <...>
       Default to configuration value of log.decorate if configured, otherwise,
       auto.
```

When you run a program with a pipe on its output, the output becomes the pipe itself, not a terminal, and as such no ref names are shown.

Comment: Thanks, although I still have some confusion.  I did read "git help log", and also search for similar questions on SO, before posting this... however I am running "git log" without any options.   I use neither --no-decorate nor --decorate, so does this still apply?

Comment: Yes, that is also described a bit after the part I've shown: `Default to configuration value of log.decorate if configured, otherwise, auto.`

Comment: What version of git are you using?  Mine does not have that text in the help, I even tried searching for it.  Thanks.

Comment: I am running version 2.35.1; it is indeed very recent and your distribution may have an older one included.

Comment: That really was a [recent change to the documentation](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0538e5c8baf9985a71d18a1495985441041efba): it has only been present since version 2.33.0.

Comment: By the way, if it was sufficient to anwer your question, please do accept the anwer.

Comment: You have been helpful, and I thank you.  I will accept the answer if you can edit to include the key information you quoted in your first comment, that --decorate defaults to auto if not specified on the command line and no value in git config (and it turns out this is missing from the 2.20 documentation).  Then it fully answers my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, that's definitely makes it better! Done.